# Fancybox2 Base64 image not work in IE

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer, fancybox, base64

I am going to use **base64** image in **fancybox**.

My code is like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.4/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.4/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.4"></script>

<a class='fancybox' rel='album' href='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAAPAKIAAAsLav///88PD9WqsYmApmZmZtZfYmdakyH5BAQUAP8ALAAAAABQAA8AAAPb
WLrc/jDKSVe4OOvNu/9gqARDSRBHegyGMahqO4R0bQcjIQ8E4BMCQc930JluyGRmdAAcdiigMLVr
ApTYWy5FKM1IQe+Mp+L4rphz+qIOBAUYeCY4p2tGrJZeH9y79mZsawFoaIRxF3JyiYxuHiMGb5KT
kpFvZj4ZbYeCiXaOiKBwnxh4fnt9e3ktgZyHhrChinONs3cFAShFF2JhvCZlG5uchYNun5eedRxM
AF15XEFRXgZWWdciuM8GCmdSQ84lLQfY5R14wDB5Lyon4ubwS7jx9NcV9/j5+g4JADs=' title='Description'"><img src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAAPAKIAAAsLav///88PD9WqsYmApmZmZtZfYmdakyH5BAQUAP8ALAAAAABQAA8AAAPb
WLrc/jDKSVe4OOvNu/9gqARDSRBHegyGMahqO4R0bQcjIQ8E4BMCQc930JluyGRmdAAcdiigMLVr
ApTYWy5FKM1IQe+Mp+L4rphz+qIOBAUYeCY4p2tGrJZeH9y79mZsawFoaIRxF3JyiYxuHiMGb5KT
kpFvZj4ZbYeCiXaOiKBwnxh4fnt9e3ktgZyHhrChinONs3cFAShFF2JhvCZlG5uchYNun5eedRxM
AF15XEFRXgZWWdciuM8GCmdSQ84lLQfY5R14wDB5Lyon4ubwS7jx9NcV9/j5+g4JADs=' style='border:0px;vertical-align:middle;margin-top:4px;margin-right:4px;margin-bottom:4px;margin-left:4px;'> </a>
```

---

It is working in all browsers (IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome), but if the base64 image is larger (the data:image/jpg is more than 60000 characters), it cannot be shown in IE.

Any experience and solution for this case?

Thank you
LW

Comment: There are limits for base64 encoded images in Internet Explorer. Why use base64 in the first place, instead of real images? Those have a number of advantages.

Comment: It's not a fancybox issue, is an IE limitation.

Comment: Thanks Pekka and JFK for your comment. It is because I store the image in mysql as binary data, each record matching with own image.

Comment: I am thinking to set fancybox's href links to a php page, the page will query from database for specify id and display the image. Is that work?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this : add a ID attribute to your picture and add the link to this ID

```
<a class='fancybox' rel='album' href='#ImgBase64' title='Description'">
<img src='data:image/gif;base64,...' ID='ImgBase64'>
</a>
```